# Fixed port number while testing Azure and Web Service Role in Debug mode

Tags: .net, web-services, msbuild, maven, azure

We're trying to test a Java client against a .NET Web Service (it's one of the "Roles" of the Azure Cloud project) - that's not really relevant except in the sense of wanting to have a quicker code-test-debug cycle.  Ideally of course, configuring the port to use on the Java client and making sure that it's always going to be the same.

**NOTE:** the Java client uses Maven to set-up the runtime configuration (and port number of the service).  The annoyance here is that the `pom.xml` file has to be edited before testing.

The question is actually: is there a scheme using MSBuild or some kind of IDE setting that allows for the .NET Web Service, Local Azure Environment, to shutdown when debugging stops in the IDE?

The end state of this configuration would be to be able to Debug the .NET Web Service, run the Java client, and shutdown everything - then be able to repeat this process without having to mess with the taskbar or modify the client's `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean in the Dev Fabric (the local emulator), is should always run on the same port. However, if that port is in use (another process, or a previous debug session didn't release it), it will use the next available port.

To free up a port that wasn't released by a pervious debug session, just stop and restart the Compute Emulator via the UI and it should revert to the configured port (unless its already in use by another process, like IIS).

Comment: Yeah, but having to mess with the UI (taskbar) is irritating.  It'd be great if VS would just shutdown the service at, say, `localhost:8080` when you stopped debugging.  Then you can just switch between VS and the prompt to quickly make edits to both and restart.

Comment: most of the time, the ports are properly freed-up. I have to take these steps once every several days.